# MCF channel report not in sync with conversion report in GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google Analytics MCF Channel Report isn't in harmony with the conversion report. Conversion from the direct traffic is much higher in the MCF report than the conversion report and conversion for 'email' is much lower in the MCF report than the conversion report. Other channels like social network etc. have less stark differences. All the traffic has been tagged properly since the conversion report is showing more believable results. Is it possible that it could be that the MCF channels take much more time to be updated properly. I checked the description for direct channel too and it just says that the medium should be none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lest you think there is something wrong with your code - not, it's just that MCF attributes differently than standard reports.

Standard attribution is "last non-direct click", so if somebody clicks on an ad, comes to your site, leaves and  returns via a direct type-in he is still attributed to the clicked ad. This is a legacy from the original Urchin product (predecessor to GA). The idea is that you can influence marketing channels but not the direct channel, so conversions are attributed to the channel that you can control (I do not necessarily agree with that idea, but that's how GA does it). Net result is that non-direct channels receive more attribution at the expense of the direct channel.

MCF however attributes the same user more correctly to the actual last channel, so it is expected behavior that their are out of synch with the standard reports.

So your tracking code and tagging are most probably correct, and it is not a problem of processing latency, it is just the the reports use different attribution models.